# PHP - Google chart API - QR code margins not working (Bug or feature? )

Tags: php, google-visualization, qr-code

I have a very simple function to generate QR code from the google chart API.

```
 function o99_qr_code($size,$type,$url ) {

        $qr = '';
        $dsize = $size .'x'.$size; // doubleSize

         $qr = '<img src="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=' . $dsize . '&chld=L|0&chl=' . $url . '" width="' .$size .'" height="'.$size .'" alt="QR code" title="QR Code for your mobile device"/>';

         switch ($type){
         case 'echo' :
         echo $qr;
         case 'return' :
         return $qr;
         }
    }
```

Now, this is working just fine except for the margin.

(Apologize for not linking a live URL - my DEV is on localmachine)

Whatver I try , I can not get the margin to go to 0.
First I thought that for some reason, maybe the correction level L does not accept 0 margins  - I tired `&chld=M|1` and `&chld=L|0` and `&chld=M|3` , and even tried to change the order of the parameters and put `&chld=L|0` to the end of the string or omitting it completely .

But for some reason, I always get the default margin of 4.

Am I doing something wrong ??

**EDIT I**  - after request of URL :
The generated URL is :

```
<img src="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=50x50&chld=L|0&chl=http://localhost/wp-sandbox/?p=6164" width="50" height="50" alt="QR code" title="QR code for your phone"/>
```

**EDIT II**

Check out this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/obmerk99/rsjcM/

it demonstrate the problem .

Comment: Can you please show the generated URL ... take a look at this `http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=200x200&cht=qr&chl=it+works+for+me&choe=UTF-8&chld=M|0`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Google charts has a curious feature where it will grow the size of the image but **not** grow the size of the code.

This will depend on the size of the data within the code.

Take a look at these three examples

150 - no margin http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=150x150&chld=L|0&chl=http://localhost/wp-sandbox/?p=6164

165 - margin http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=165x165&chld=L|0&chl=http://localhost/wp-sandbox/?p=6164

180 - no margin http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=180x180&chld=L|0&chl=http://localhost/wp-sandbox/?p=6164

Remember - you code *needs* a margin in order for the majority of devices to scan it properly.

Comment: ok, +1 for the explanation, but what is the solution ? how can one calculate when the image only grows, and when the margins ?

Comment: check the fiddle . how can somone calculate those values ? how to know which sizes will give 0 margin ??

Comment: As per your question, I think it's a bug. The only real solution is to use another QR generator, or accept the small margin.

Comment: after long time experimenting I think that it depends on the server which replies the request .. moving a lot for work , I found that the same sites can give different results. when operating from a PROXY and reloading the same page , the result can change . I guess only google has the answers (like always :-)  )

Comment: Find the documentation here: https://developers.google.com/chart/infographics/docs/qr_codes

Answer (score 2):

Same problems here with the Google API. So I ended up using this alternative service: http://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=http://www.google.com&size=104x104

The API (http://qrserver.com/api/documentation/create-qr-code/) offers better control of the desired QR Code image output.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem when generating lots of QR-Code with various encoded data size.

What I found so far is that the generation code probably impose the **same number of screen-pixels size for each barcode-pixels**.

So, assuming:

- `sw` the QR-code height/width you ask for, in screen-pixel, let's say 150x150 pixels
- `bw` the number of barcode-pixel of the encoded data, let's say 20x20 pixels
- `cw` the number of screen-pixel per barcode-pixel: `cw = ceil(sw /bw)`, so here 150/20 = 7,5 => cw=7
- `sw2` the barcode real width in pixel: `sw2 = cw * bw`, so here sw2=7*20=140 pixels
- `mw` the margin width in pixels: `mw = (sw - sw2) / 2`, so here a margin of 5 pixels...

With the same example, if you ask for a 160x160 size QR code you will problably have no margins: 160/20=8.

To come back to your initial problem, decreasing variability in margin size means either decreasing the number of barcode pixel (but you can't control that as it depends on QR-code quality and size of encoded data), or increasing resulting screen-pixel dimensions.

If you ask for an infinite dimension there is no more variation in margin, but I wonder if Google would be happy with that :)